# Laravel 5 - expected location for a singleton

Tags: laravel, singleton, laravel-5

Hello guys !

I want to create a singleton for my oauth server, like this :

```
App::singleton('oauth2', function() {
    // connect to the oauth2 server, check grant type, client credentials....
});
```

Currently it's in my routes, and it works... I call it in a route just a little after. But it annoys me that it's here, it kinda feels not in its place. Beginning with Laravel, I could use a little help :)

Thanks ahead !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a [Service Provider](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/providers) for this. First create the provider with this command:

```
php artisan make:provider OAuthServiceProvider
```

The new provider will be generated in `app/Providers/OAuthServiceProvider.php`. Then register the singleton in the `register` method of the provider:

```php
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class OAuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('oauth2', function()
        {
            // connect to the oauth2 server, check grant type, client credentials....
        });
    }

}
```

Then add the new provider to the `providers` array in `config/app.php`:

```php
'providers' => [
    ...
    'App\Providers\OAuthServiceProvider',
]
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. After that I can use it everywhere in the app freely, or do I have to write "use" with its path at the beginning of the file, or inject it as a dependency in the functions, or both ?

Comment: I used it without problem. Thanks again.